# How do I retrieve and display objects from parse to a table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, location

I've looked everywhere and in Parse's documentation and am having trouble using and understanding how to get nearby (parse custom objects) users from their geopoints. I need to also display the names of these users who are nearby in sets of table view cells but I need help getting started.

```
class DiscoverVC: UIViewController {

var userLocation = PFGeoPoint()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    queryForTable()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    queryForTable()
}

func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let userGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint = self.userLocation
    let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    query.whereKey("Location", nearGeoPoint: self.userLocation, withinKilometers: 5)
    query.limit = 10
    query.includeKey("FirstName")
    query.includeKey("LastName")
    return query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite some different ways on doing this. If you are using `queryForTable()` to retrieve your data so you may extend your class as a `PFQueryTableViewController`.

Than you should make some initialization:

```
  // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
  override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "_ User"
    //column you wish to display
    self.textKey = "columnName"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
  }
```

If you have any problem this [tutorial](http://blog.bizzi-body.com/2015/02/05/ios-swift-parse-com-part-2-table-view/) will help you a lot.